# Kernel density estimation in the limit of infinity many samples

Tags: probability, statistics, measure-theory

Let ($x_1, ..., x_n$) be i.i.d. samples drawn from some distribution $P$ with an unknown probability density function $f$. Its kernel density estimator is
\begin{align}
    \hat{f}_h(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n K_h (x - x_i) \quad = \frac{1}{nh} \sum_{i=1}^n K\Big(\frac{x-x_i}{h}\Big),
\end{align}
where $K$ a symmetric non-negative function that integrates to one.

I am interested what happens in the limit $n \to \infty$. Are there any publications that prove 
\begin{align}
    \hat{f}_h(x) &= \int K_h (x - x_i) \text{d}x \quad \text{or} \\
&= \int K_h (x - x_i) \text{d}P ?
\end{align}
Is then in the limit $\hat{f}_h(x) = f$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking about the *consistency* of kernel density estimates. See this [paper](http://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/39692/1/tr03-09.pdf) to shows that such estimators are generally consistent under modest conditions.