# Consistency of kernel density estimator with constant bandwidth

Tags: statistics, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let ($x_1, ..., x_n$) be i.i.d. samples drawn from some distribution $P$ with an unknown probability density function $f$. Its *kernel density estimator* is
\begin{align}
    \hat{f}_h(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n K_h (x - x_i) \quad = \frac{1}{nh} \sum_{i=1}^n K\Big(\frac{x-x_i}{h}\Big),
\end{align}
where $K$ a symmetric non-negative function that integrates to one.

All consistency proofs ([1](http://bayes.wustl.edu/Manual/parzen62.pdf),[2](http://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/39692/1/tr03-09.pdf)) require that $h(n) \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$ and I think remember that this is a necessary condition for strong and even weak consistency. Are there any analysis about what happens when the bandwidth $h$ is a constant? Maybe error some bounds on the convergence to $f$?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of the question you asked earlier: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914789/kernel-density-estimation-in-the-limit-of-infinity-many-samples/915595#915595

Comment: They are similar.
The question earlier was about consistency in general and the got correctly answered. Here I am explicitly interested in a constant bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a question of error bounds (a so-called *second-order* condition), but of *first order* convergence. If an estimator is not consistent, then it does not converge to the true value (i.e., **bias**), its not that it has a high degree of inter sample variability (i.e., **sampling variance**). See this [paper](http://matematicas.unex.es/~jechacon/index_archivos/ChaconRodriguezCasal2010.pdf), especially remark 6 on page 4.

As a simple example, what is the bound on the error of the following estimator:

Let $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,1),\;\;\; \hat \mu = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i + 50$