# Empirical Process estimation using gaussian density and specific random generator

Tags: random-variables, random, gaussian-integral

EDITED: To formulate into math framework:

I have a sampling generator producing IID gaussian.
To highlight the convergence in the distribution, I calculate the following error.

Given a precision step m and a bandwitdh H, a theoritical density D,
The sample (xn) have the following distribution error:

$$E(n,m)=|I_{n,m} - Jm|$$
$$I_{n,m}=1/m \sum_1^m f(ci). PI(ui,u_{i+1},n)$$
$$PI(ui,u_{i+1},n)= \sum_1^n 1_{x_k∈[ui,u_{i+1}[}  $$
$$ci =( ui+u_{i+1} )/2$$
$$ui = H/m  $$

$$Jm=1/m \sum_1^m f(ci). D(ci).dui$$

Does this error make sense ?
Since Central Limit theorem only gives asymptotic error, would like to compute a more precise error.

Comment: I don't think I understand why you would pose this question when the Box-Muller and Ziggurat algorithms both provably furnish the correct distribution (up to issues with computer arithmetic). That is to say, at least for the normal distribution in particular, there is no good reason to use a discretization.

Comment: Hi,

1) Box Muller / Ziggurat are NOT random generator algorithm. They are transformation functions : Uniform to Gaussian sample.

2) The goal is to compare 2 random generators algorithm (Uniform ones) to see whether which one provides the most uniform and well distributed ones.

Comment: Yes, they map uniform to Gaussian...but to my knowledge this is always easier than generating Gaussian directly.

Comment: Yes...

1) My Random Generators generates Uniform.
  From Uniform --> Inverse Transform Gaussian.

2) In the end, I compare directly the Gaussians rather the Uniform (altough we can compare the uniforms, but the end calculation using gaussian).

3) I would like to benchmark those 2 random generators....(hence, the purpose of my question.... if benchmark against density is stupid or could make sense...)

Comment: You have two different *uniform* generators and are trying to compare them through the Gaussian outputs? You didn't say that...

Comment: Uniform --> Inverse Tranform  --> Gaussian Output.

Q: How much "stable" is the output ?

Do you have any way to assess it ?
(other than normality test.... since they are normal..)

Answer (score 0):

After resesarch, this question relates to Kernel Density Smoothing and estimation from empirical distribution:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation

KDE should converge to the theoritical when the number of sample increases...

How this convergence is done,  is related to the random generator structure.

Another item is the consistency of Kernel Density estimator at asymptotics, when the sample becomes infinite.

This is here:

[Kernel density estimation in the limit of infinity many samples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914789/kernel-density-estimation-in-the-limit-of-infinity-many-samples)

Additionnally, this question is related to the estimation of the sampling error in sampling the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

This problem relates to empirical distribution theory. Here, a complete treatment of the subject:

EMPIRICAL PROCESSES: Theory and Applications
https://www.stat.washington.edu/jaw/RESEARCH/TALKS/Delft/emp-proc-delft-big.pdf